# How send multiple images to server in flutter web with json?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Want to send multiple data to the api in flutter but doesn't know how to set multiple body to the request.

```
 List<dynamic>? _pickedImages = [];

  Future<void> _pickMultiImages() async {
    List<dynamic>? fromPicker =
        await ImagePickerWeb.getMultiImages(outputType: ImageType.widget);

    if (fromPicker != null) {
      setState(() => _pickedImages = fromPicker);
      print(_pickedImages!.length);
    }
}
```

Then send the data to the api

```
Future uploadimages() async {

    final uploadurl = 'http://localhost:9000/api/v1/upload';
    
    Map<String, String> body = Map<String, String>();
    var userData;

    // for (var image in _pickedImages!) {
    //   String fileInBase64 = base64Encode(image.image.bytes);
    //   // userData = json.encode({
    //   //   "creator": {"creatorId": "298", "createDate": "2018-12-21 20:44:45.8"},
    //   //   "info": "$fileInBase64",
    //   // });
    // }

    }
    // print(body);
    final upload = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(uploadurl),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
      body: body,
    );

    if (upload.statusCode == 201) {
      return upload.body;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed');
    }
  }
```

How i can create json like
{
"file1": "data:image/png;base64,bla bla",
"file2": "data:image/png;base64,bla bla",
"file3": "data:image/png;base64,bla bla"
} from  _pickedImages after encode image to base64

Please Help.

Comment: Maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327288/how-to-set-a-field-with-multi-value-into-a-post-request) can be of help to you.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say, im using flutter web.